# VMware Powercli Get-Snapshot

Tags: powershell, powercli

Using VMWare PowerCLI, how can I set a snapshot of a VM without getting the confirmation prompt?

```
Get-Snapshot -VM VM -Name 'snapshotname'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-Snapshot -VM VM -Name 'snapshotname' -confirm:$false
```